# Specify region codes when writing a dvd using C#

Tags: c#

How to specify region codes when writing a dvd using C#

Comment: Referring, [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/mydvdregion.aspx) can help you, in this issue.

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441227/how-to-burn-video-dvd-from-c) is discussing burning DVDs.
[This project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/imapi2.aspx) too. Noting about regions though.
I believe, DVDs you burn are typically region free. Only commercial movie DVDs have a region defined on them.